# How to call the instance of class?

Tags: php, neo4j, recommendation-engine

I am using the setup, I download and setup package from github with link below:

https://github.com/graphaware/reco4php

I have also installed the php7 and neo7j they are running properly on localhost (ubuntu16.04).

I am getting error in browser:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Demo\Github\RecommendationEngine' not found in /var/www/html/recommendation_2/example.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/recommendation_2/example.php on line 9
```

when hit example.php form browser.example.php file code below:

```
<?php
// example.php file

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Demo\Github\RecommendationEngine;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\RecommenderService;

$rs = RecommenderService::create("http://neo4j:idealindore@localhost:7474");
$rs->registerRecommendationEngine(new RecommendationEngine());

$stopwatch = new \Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch();

$input = $rs->findInputBy('User', 'login', 'jakzal');

$engine = $rs->getRecommender("github_who_to_follow");

$stopwatch->start('reco');
$recommendations = $engine->recommend($input);
$e = $stopwatch->stop('reco');

//echo $recommendations->size() . ' found in ' . $e->getDuration() .  'ms' .PHP_EOL;

foreach ($recommendations->getItems(10) as $reco) {
    echo $reco->item()->get('login') . PHP_EOL;
    echo $reco->totalScore() . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($reco->getScores() as $name => $score) {
        echo "\t" . $name . ':' . $score->score() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I also setup for reco4j and getting the same error, If someone help for solving this issue, it will help for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes I am also looking for the solution, I am trying too for to run the setup, If I get the solution I will post here. If you get any solution please inform.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you did not use the right path to the classes.

Change This :

```
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Demo\Github\RecommendationEngine;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\RecommenderService;
```

to where you actually store These files.

- RecommendationEngine.php
- RecommenderService.php

Beside you also need to use these classes :

```
use GraphAware\Common\Cypher\Statement;
use GraphAware\Common\Type\Node;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Context\Context;
use GraphAware\Reco4PHP\Engine\SingleDiscoveryEngine;
```

See [This Link](https://github.com/graphaware/reco4php) and follow the tutorial step by step to learn how to build a graph base recommendation system with Neo4J.

Also Check [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429823/neo4j-graphaware-reco4php-problem-with-namespaces/52430844#52430844) if you have any problem with the tutorial.